# Stripe Subscription Schedules Charge Instantly

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

when you create a stripe "Subscription Schedules" with 1000$, it will keep the invoice in draft for 1 hour, then pay it.
My code example:

```
                $subscription = $stripe->subscriptionSchedules->create([
                    'customer' => $customer->id,
                    'start_date' => 'now',
                    'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
                    'phases' => $phase,
                ]);
```

I found a way to make the first payment.

```
                    $subs = $stripe->subscriptions->retrieve(
                         $subscription->subscription,
                         []
                    );
                        $lastInvoice = $subs->latest_invoice;
                        $stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice(
                            $lastInvoice,
                            [
                                'auto_advance' => true
                            ]
                        );

                        $stripe->invoices->pay(
                            $lastInvoice,
                            [
                                'source' => $source->id
                            ]
                        );
```

But the next day's invoice will be $0.
I need help.
Thank you!

Pay the subscription schedule invoice instantly without waiting for an hour, and all subsequent invoices. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe finalizes and sends the invoice in 1 hour[1]. Before the invoice is finalized, you can edit it. Read more about making changes in the Invoice details page.

You can force to pay the invoice by calling these two APIs, finalize[2] and pay[3] (assuming you have an attached payment method to the Customer[5])

You can do several tests using Stripe Test Clocks[6].

[1] [https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#:~:text=Stripe%20finalizes%20and%20sends%20the%20invoice%20in%201%20hour](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#:%7E:text=Stripe%20finalizes%20and%20sends%20the%20invoice%20in%201%20hour)

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/finalize

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

[6] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks

Comment: I solved the problem that the first invoice will be paid immediately but the next invoice on the schedule is $0. Can you help me?

Comment: There shouldn't be an additional invoice of 0$, unless you have particular pricing...